# How to generate all-projects-in-one Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, maven-central, maven-publish

I have a gradle monolithic project with too many dependencies.

I'd like to explode it into many sub-projects and publish all sub-projects (build + sources + javadoc) + an extra project being the merge of all sub-projects.

This extra project should be like a virtual artifact with all my projects in a single jar like it is today because I don't want a too big change for my users.

The jar must not include dependencies (it is not an uber-jar) but the resulted pom.xml must contain the dependencies of all sub-projects (the generated pom.xml of the maven artifact must contain all dependencies).

The virtual artifact will include the merge of javadoc and sources too in order to respect Maven Central conventions.

Current state:

- Project Main, generate

  - pom.xml
  - main.jar
  - main-sources.jar
  - main-javadoc.jar

Expected state:

- Subproject A, generate

  - A-pom.xml
  - A.jar
  - A-sources.jar
  - A-javadoc.jar
- Subproject B, generate

  - B-pom.xml
  - B.jar
  - B-sources.jar
  - B-javadoc.jar
- **virtal**-Project Main, generate

  - pom.xml=A-pom.xml+B-pom.xml
  - main.jar=A.jar+B.jar
  - main-sources.jar=A-sources.jar+B-sources.jar
  - main-javadoc.jar=A-javadoc.jar+B-javadoc.jar

How can I manage it?

Comment: Maybe you be a bit more specific as to what you are asking? From what I get, you pretty much just do what you describe :) You may find the chapter on [multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) in the user guide useful if you haven't read it already.

Comment: @BjørnVester Thank you for your interest. Creating sub-projects is not a problem but I don't want a too big change for my users. 
So I'd like to keep a virtual artifact with all my projects in a single jar like today (including the merge of javadoc and sources artifacts). The jar must not include dependencies but the resulted pom.xml must contains the dependencies of all sub-projects.
I hope my ask is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, it is much more clear now. I initially thought you wanted to publish and use sub-projects while having binary inter-dependencies in Maven and source dependencies in the build. I don't have an answer for merging subprojects in a way to produce the same result as the monolithic approach though.

Comment: Where this requirement is being defined: "The virtual artifact will include the merge of javadoc and sources too in order to respect Maven Central conventions." ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been in exactly the same situation for some time now. We want to publish a single artifact for our clients to depend on, although internally the product is developed through a few separate component projects. I got it done eventually (with compromises), and here is what I learned:

1. Merging jars is not as straightforward as it looks like because there could be things like resource files within a jar that are not
   always namespace-ed. It is possible that two of your jars have a
   resource file with the same name, in which case you will have to
   merge the content of those files.
2. Javadoc is very hard to merge without accessing the original source
   files because it has summary pages (index pages).

So my advice would be:

- Think twice, maybe what you really want is **NOT** a single jar, but **a single dependency** for your clients? These are different. You can easily have a pom only artifact. Depending on this pom only artifact will simply translates transitively into depending on individual artifacts of your component sub projects. To your client, practically, nothing is changed. Spring Boot takes this approach. To do it, you can create an empty java-library project, make all your component projects its `api` dependency. You don't even need any source code in this project.
- If you really want to merge into a single jar, you can try building a fat jar with customization. The customization is not to pull in 3rd party dependencies.

We use the [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin for merging jars. Its original purpose was to build a fat jar, which will include all the transitive dependencies. But it also has a special "`shadow`" configuration, to which you can add dependencies if you want the dependencies to be exported into POM rather than bundled. So what you need to do:

1. Define a **non-transitive** configuration (say **bundler**) to which you will add your sub-project as dependencies. This is going to be the target configuration for the Gradle Shadow plugin.
2. Define a **transitive** configuration (**bundlerTransitive**) that extends from your non-transitive one. This will be manually resolved in order to find the 3rd party dependencies
3. in your build.gradle, register an `afterEvaluate` closure, where you find the **level two** dependencies of the **resolved** transitive configuration, add them to the `shadow` configuration. The reason for level-two is that level one dependencies will be your sub-project artifacts.
4. After all the above, the artifact produced by shadowJar task is the one to be uploaded to maven. You will need to configure the shadowJar task to remove the classifier (which is *shadow* by default)

Here is a complete example (build.gradle) of bundling vertx-web and all its dependencies within the io.vertx group:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    bundler {
        transitive = false
    }

    bundlerTansitive {
        extendsFrom bundler
        transitive = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    bundler "io.vertx:vertx-web:4.0.0"
    bundler "io.vertx:vertx-web-common:4.0.0"
    bundler "io.vertx:vertx-core:4.0.0"
    bundler "io.vertx:vertx-auth-common:4.0.0"
    bundler "io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common:4.0.0"
}

shadowJar {
    configurations = [project.configurations.bundler]
    classifier ''
}


publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            project.shadow.component(publication)
        }
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    // this is needed because your sub-projects might have inter-dependencies
    def isBundled = { ResolvedDependency dep ->
        return configurations.bundler.dependencies.any {
            dep.moduleGroup == it.group && dep.moduleName == it.name
        }
    }

    logger.lifecycle '\nBundled artifacts and their 1st level dependencies:'

    // level one dependencies
    configurations.bundlerTansitive.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.forEach {
        logger.lifecycle "+--- ${it.getName()}"

        // level two dependencies
        it.children.findAll({ ResolvedDependency dep -> !isBundled(dep) })
                .forEach { ResolvedDependency dep ->
                    logger.lifecycle "|    +--- ${dep.name}"
                    project.dependencies.add('shadow', [group: dep.moduleGroup, name: dep.moduleName, version: dep.moduleVersion])
                }
    }

    logger.lifecycle '\nExported Dependencies:'

    configurations.shadow.getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().forEach {
        project.logger.lifecycle "+--- ${it.getName()}"
    }
}
```

For javadoc if you don't care about the index (compromise, as I said), then it is just a jar task with a copy spec:

```
configurations {
   javadoc {
        transitive = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    javadoc 'com.my:component-a:1.1.0:javadoc'
    javadoc 'com.my:component-b:1.1.0:javadoc'
    javadoc 'com.my:component-c:1.1.0:javadoc'
    javadoc 'com.my:component-d:1.1.0:javadoc'
}

task javadocFatJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set('javadoc')
    from { 
        configurations.javadoc.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. Do you have any examples for the Shadow plugin? I'm not sure to understand how to exclude 3rd party dependencies from the generated jar.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include a mini example. Depending on your other needs you might want to do a bit more in the afterEvaluate block, e.g. if you dependencies are specified with dynamic versions, you might want to resolve the bundler configuration first to lock the version etc.

Comment: However, you should firstly consider not bundling the jars if possible, which is pretty much always the right choice I think. Getting the bundling to work feels technically an achievement, but it has implications for the overall SLDC process especially when you are building a library.

Comment: I agree, I will try the BOM-like solution first :)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with `maven-publish` directly, but one can add individual `java-library` modules and package each of them with sources and docs. With Gradle this would be a simple `jar` task, but when the artifacts are publicly available ...such transitive dependencies should better be provided by a meta package; nothing but Maven (Local/Central) dependencies, instead of embedded JARS. In this case, this would be just another module (which obviously would only build after having published the others).

And concerning the concept, that it would require any "merged" JavaDocs ...
https://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html#supply-javadoc-and-sources
While they're referenced (Maven Central) in `*.pom`, Gradle will be able to find them.
Just use repository `mavenLocal()` instead of `mavenCentral()` for testing purposes.