# Configure the build to publish a single jar to Artifactory?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, gradlew

My Gradle project is arranged as follows:

```
<MyLib>
build.gradle
       |——>sub_module1
               build.gradle
       |——>sub_module2
               build.gradle
```

The Project segregates the public API from implementation by having two separate gradle sub-modules i.e, sub_module1 and sub_module2. However, I would like to hide this segregation from external users and provide them with a single artifact jar i.e configure the build to publish a single jar to the Artifactory, which merges both  sub_module1 & sub_module2 into a single Jar (with a single version) So they can use it as API dependency rather than implementing sub-modules in there build.gradle for `dependencies`

In short something like

```
dependencies { 
   api "com.mypackage:MyLib:$MyLibVersion"
}
```

to be used by the end-user of my library.

instead, the user saying

```
dependencies { 
    implementation "package:sub_module1:$MyLibVersion"
    implementation "package:sub_module2:$MyLibVersion"
}
```

Comment: It sounds like this question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65173003/1797912); or is there anything missing in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65237462/1797912) to that question that we could clarify here? For example, I’m a bit confused about your `api` vs. `implementation` concern; IMHO, it shouldn’t make a difference downstream, whether you publish a single JAR or multiple JARs.